# Create a metric on X

Tags: complex-numbers, metric-spaces

Let $X=\{a+bi|a,b \in \mathbb{R} \ni a^2+b^2=1\}$. Create a metric on X.

I know that $X$ is a subset of the complex numbers, and since $a^2+b^2=1$, we have $|z|=1$. So the distance of the point $z$ from the origin is $1$.

Lemma: If $b \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $b \ge 0$, then $|a| \le b \iff -b \le a \le b$.

Define $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{C}$ by $d(z,w)=|z-w|$.

M1) $\forall z \in X$, we have $d(z,z)=|z-z|=|0|=0$.

M2) Suppose $z,w \in X \ni d(z,w)=0$. Then $|z-w|=0 \iff z-w=0 \Rightarrow z=w$.

M3) Consider $d(z,w)$ in two cases:

Case 1: If $z=w$, then $d(z,w)=d(w,z)=0$.

Case 2: If $z \ne w$, then $d(z,w) \ne d(w,z)$. Thus $d(z,w)=d(w,z) \Rightarrow z=w$.

In both cases, $d(z,w)=d(w,z)$.

My question here is that since | | represents the modulus of the complex number, then $|z-w|=1$ and $|w-z|=1$? So $d(z,w)=d(w,z)$?

M4) Let $z,w,y \in X$.

Note that $-|z-y| \le z-y \le |z-y|$ and that $-|y-w| \le y-w \le |y-w|$. So $(-|z-y| \le z-y \le |z-y|) + (-|y-w| \le y-w \le |y-w|)=-(|z-y|+|y-w|) \le z-w \le (|z-y|+|y-w|)$. Because $|z-y|+|y-w| \ge 0$, then by the lemma we can let $b=|z-y|+|y-w|$. Thus $|z-w| \le |z-y|+|y-w|$, and hence $d(z,w) \le d(z,y)+d(y,w)$.

I'm also not sure where to use the condition that $|z|=1$.

Another metric I was thinking about is for $u,v \in X$, define $d(u,v)=||u-v||$. But after checking M1 to M4 for this metric, I realized that I didn't need the $|z|=1$. I could be misinterpreting the problem, so any insight would be appreciated.

**Edit**

$F$ denotes $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, and $V$ denotes a vector space over $F$.

$X=\{a+bi | a,b \in \mathbb{R} \ni a^2+b^2=1\}$.

Lemma: $\forall \lambda \in F,||\lambda v||=|\lambda|||v||.$

Proof. Suppose $\lambda \in F$, and $v \in V$. Then $||\lambda v||^2=\langle \lambda v, \lambda v \rangle=\lambda \langle v, \lambda v \rangle$ (by homogeneity in the first slot) $=\lambda \bar{\lambda} \langle v, v \rangle$ (by complex homogeneity in the second slot). Because $|\lambda|^2=\lambda \bar{\lambda}$, we have $||\lambda v||^2 = |\lambda|^2||v||^2$ and thus $||\lambda v||= |\lambda|||v||$.

For $u,v \in X$, define $d(u,v)=||u-v||$.

M1) $\forall u \in X$, we have $d(u,u)=\sqrt{\langle u-u, u-u \rangle}=\sqrt{\langle 0, 0 \rangle}=\sqrt{0}=0$.

M2) Suppose $u,v \in X \ni d(u,v)=||u-v||=0$.

Then by properties of the norm, $||u-v||=0 \iff u-v=0$, so $u=v$.

M3) Consider $d(u,v)=||u-v||$.

Here $||u-v||=||(-1)(v-u)||$, and by the lemma, $||(-1)(v-u)||=|-1|||v-u||=||v-u|| \Rightarrow d(u,v) = d(v,u)$.

M4) Let $u,w,v \in X$.

$d(u,v)^2 = \langle u-v, u-v \rangle = \langle (u-w)+(w-v), (u-w)+(w-v) \rangle = \langle u-w, u-w \rangle +2\langle u-w, w-v \rangle + \langle w-v, w-v \rangle \le d(u,w)^2 + 2|\langle u-w, w-v \rangle| + d(w,v)^2$.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, $d(u,w)^2 + 2|\langle u-w, w-v \rangle| + d(w,v)^2 \le d(u,w)^2+2||u-w||||w-v||+d(w,v)^2=d(u,w)^2+2d(u,w)d(w,v)+d(w,v)^2=(d(u,w)+d(w,v))^2$.

As $d(u,v),d(u,w),d(w,v)$ are non-negative, this implies that $d(u,v) \le d(u,w)+d(w,v)$.

Therefore, $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

Comment: Of course there are many different metrics that would solve the problem "create a metric on $X$".  If that is the only requirement, then any one of them will be a solution.

Comment: Remark:  Using $\ni$ for "such that" will be understood by only a few readers.

Comment: M3 case 2 is complete nonsense. $z\ne w$ does not imply $d(z,w) \ne d(w,z)$. And even if that were true, it directly contradicts the result you claim to obtain from it.

Comment: The difference between two complex numbers on the unit circle does not have to be on the unit circle itself. In fact, for any point $z$ on the unit circle there are exactly two other points $w$ on the circle with $|z-w| = 1$. For the uncountably many other points on the unit circle that $w$ could be, $|z-w| \ne 1$.

Comment: For your final question, $d(z,w) = |z - w|$ is a metric on all of $\Bbb C$. As such, it is also a metric on any subset of $C$, such at the unit circle. I.e., You didn't find a place to use $|z| = 1$ because it isn't necessary. $|z - w|$ is a metric even when $|z|$ is allowed to not be $1$.